# How to include PHP code in the CSS class in the background-image URL () property

Tags: php, css

I have a script, and I have to include image path using PHP code in the CSS stylesheet. But when I try to adding PHP code in my CSS class background-image URL () property file nothing occurs! Is it possible?

```
div.home-banner {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("<?php echo APP_HOME_BANNER_IMAGE; ?>");

}
```

Comment: You can't use PHP code in a `.css` file... If this is a `<style>` element in a `.php` file, then this code would work, but you can't mix/match languages like that.

Comment: Thank you.
Yes, i have try it's works fine in inline CSS.

`<div class="big-banner text-white" style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),url(<?php echo APP_HOME_BANNER_IMAGE; ?>)">`

Comment: "_You can't use PHP code in a .css file_" ... unless you tell your server to parse .css files using PHP - which has its downsides

Comment: Exactly; that code will work fine in inline CSS syntax as the file is a `.php` file, but you won't be able to move that to a `.css` file.

Comment: I just solve this issue using static path link image in in the CSS stylesheet. I don't know is it right process!
`div.home-banner {
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),url(../images/banners/tes-about-us-banner.jpg);

}`

Answer (score 0):

You would essentially have two options:

**Move this CSS code**

This would mean removing this code from the `.css` file and putting it in the `.php` page in a `<style>` element.  Then PHP wouldn't see any difference between this or any other code on a `.php` page.

The downside, of course, is that you'd be re-coupling some de-coupled CSS/HTML code.  Which isn't terrible, but could be distasteful depending on personal preference.

**Enable PHP on `.css` files**

You *could* configure your server to also process `.css` files through the PHP engine, just as it does with `.php` files.  PHP can process any files you like, it just only processes `.php` files by default.

The downside here is that you'd always be invoking the PHP engine for all `.css` files, when the vast majority of cases don't require it.

---

Which approach you choose is up to your personal preference.  I'd personally prefer the former, as it's a more obvious thing to support in ongoing code (since the latter is rarely done and unexpected).

Comment: In that case, could he change the name of the file to `file_name.pcss` or `file_name.php.css` and configure PHP to only process files with the extension `.pcss` or `php.css`?

Comment: @Lucas: That could be a workable compromise actually.  As long as the server still returns the correct content type for `.pcss` files (which may or may not need to be configured, depending on the server) since the browser wouldn't be concerned with the extension of the file name.  Though unless the OP expects to need this functionality in other styling it still feels like overkill to me.  Personal preference and ongoing expectations weigh heavily in the choices here.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve that issue.

I like to import css in a php file to use php in it.
It is pretty easy to declare the header type:

```
header("Content-type: text/css;charset=UTF-8");
```

now we can use css and php in the style.php:

```
<?php 
 header("Content-type: text/css;charset=UTF-8"); 
 include("more.css");
 echo '
 .whatever {
 }
 ';
 ?>
```

That way you can link the file like a regular .css file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.php" media="screen"/>
```

Now comes another theory, but i never tried it and it can be completly wrong.
We can use the AddType in a .htaccess file to allow php in files like a .html,
so in theory that should work too:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .css
```

But tbh, i never tried if that would work.